# Why is every popular website removing colors?

Tags: website-design, color, mobile-web

I didn't know where to ask, so I'm trying here.

I don't know if you  guys have noticed, but youtube (logo, like/dislike etc.), facebook (like & comment icon), g+ (same) etc. have removed all colors, applying only gray scales. IMO it is really bad, makes it more difficult to notice if that button is pressed or not.

Second, on mobiles, popular apps including facebook, gmail etc. have started to include an in-app mini-browser.

**1. Why in the world would they remove colors where it counts?**

**2. Why do they always copy each-other exactly and immediately?**

Comment: You're asking at least three different questions here... please try to narrow this down

Answer (score 2):

OK, let me try to answer your questions

**1. Why in the world would they remove colors where it counts?**

They don't. That's exactly the point. They use it only **WHERE IT COUNTS**, just like you say. Let me explain:

- These elements you mention are secondary actions, so they don't care for them since the focus should be put on main actions and CTAs
- They might be repeated frequently, so adding color to them would create a lot of cognitive load since you users will be attracted to lots of stimuli that don't matter.
- They're in *neutral* state, and when user interacts with them, they get color, but in the meanwhile, they need to be neutral and have no additional information whatsoever until the user interacts with them
- They get assured visualization is the same for most kind of users, including those with color blindness

---

**2. Why do they always copy each-other exactly and immediately?**

Well, keep in mind most of your example apps are owned and developed by the same company. But there's also a process of **competition analysis** and **[benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmarking)**. If I see a successful company is doing something, I have to understand WHY are they doing it, and WHAT competitive advantages will that provide to my business.

Since in UX testing is of vital importance, and you're talking about companies with huge UX departments, I'm sure they have tested each feature extensively. And this includes the benchmarking side.